# R, how can I transpose a one-column vector into a NxM matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following one-column matrix, made of a value column (the values), a column for the X coordinates, and a column for the Y coordinates.

```
X       Y       value
-       -       -
100     100     0.216
6100    100     0.00109
12100   100     0.00853
18100   100     0.0197
24100   100     0.000038
100     6100    0.506
6100    6100    0.00231
12100   6100    0.0125
18100   6100    0.0306
24100   6100    3.36E-005
100     12100   0.506
6100    12100   0.00231
12100   12100   0.0159
18100   12100   0.0329
24100   12100   3.93E-007
100     18100   0.506
6100    18100   0.00292
12100   18100   0.0163
18100   18100   0.000243
24100   18100   8.20E-007
100     24100   0.506
6100    24100   0.00322
12100   24100   0.000182
18100   24100   0.00019
24100   24100   5.38E-006
```

I want to transform it into this matrix:

```
X\Y       100   6100    12100   18100   24100
100     0.216   0.00109 0.00853 0.0197  0.000038
6100    0.506   0.00231 0.0125  0.0306  0.0000336
12100   0.506   0.00231 0.0159  0.0329  0.000000393
18100   0.506   0.00292 0.0163  0.000243    0.00000082
24100   0.506   0.00322 0.000182    0.00019 0.00000538
```

How could I do this in R?
Is there a function that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Y ~ X)

#       Y   100    6100    12100    18100    24100
# 1   100 0.216 0.00109 0.008530 0.019700 3.80e-05
# 2  6100 0.506 0.00231 0.012500 0.030600 3.36e-05
# 3 12100 0.506 0.00231 0.015900 0.032900 3.93e-07
# 4 18100 0.506 0.00292 0.016300 0.000243 8.20e-07
# 5 24100 0.506 0.00322 0.000182 0.000190 5.38e-06
```

Should you want the values 100, 6100, ... to be the names of the rows you could do:

```
final <- dcast(df, Y ~ X)
rownames(final) <- final[, 1]
final[, 1] <- NULL

# final
#         100    6100    12100    18100    24100
# 100   0.216 0.00109 0.008530 0.019700 3.80e-05
# 6100  0.506 0.00231 0.012500 0.030600 3.36e-05
# 12100 0.506 0.00231 0.015900 0.032900 3.93e-07
# 18100 0.506 0.00292 0.016300 0.000243 8.20e-07
# 24100 0.506 0.00322 0.000182 0.000190 5.38e-06
```

Here is the data:

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(100L, 6100L, 12100L, 18100L, 24100L, 100L, 
6100L, 12100L, 18100L, 24100L, 100L, 6100L, 12100L, 18100L, 24100L, 
100L, 6100L, 12100L, 18100L, 24100L, 100L, 6100L, 12100L, 18100L, 
24100L), Y = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 6100L, 6100L, 6100L, 
6100L, 6100L, 12100L, 12100L, 12100L, 12100L, 12100L, 18100L, 
18100L, 18100L, 18100L, 18100L, 24100L, 24100L, 24100L, 24100L, 
24100L), value = c(0.216, 0.00109, 0.00853, 0.0197, 3.8e-05, 
0.506, 0.00231, 0.0125, 0.0306, 3.36e-05, 0.506, 0.00231, 0.0159, 
0.0329, 3.93e-07, 0.506, 0.00292, 0.0163, 0.000243, 8.2e-07, 
0.506, 0.00322, 0.000182, 0.00019, 5.38e-06)), .Names = c("X", 
"Y", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `xtabs` in base R:

```
xtabs(value~Y+X, df)

#       X
#Y               100        6100       12100       18100       24100
#  100   0.216000000 0.001090000 0.008530000 0.019700000 0.000038000
#  6100  0.506000000 0.002310000 0.012500000 0.030600000 0.000033600
#  12100 0.506000000 0.002310000 0.015900000 0.032900000 0.000000393
#  18100 0.506000000 0.002920000 0.016300000 0.000243000 0.000000820
#  24100 0.506000000 0.003220000 0.000182000 0.000190000 0.000005380
```

Comment: You can add `sparse = T` to `xtabs` as well to produce sparse representations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and `dcast.data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(data = setDT(dx),formula = X~Y)
#        X      100     6100    12100    18100    24100
# 1:   100 0.216000 5.06e-01 5.06e-01 5.06e-01 5.06e-01
# 2:  6100 0.001090 2.31e-03 2.31e-03 2.92e-03 3.22e-03
# 3: 12100 0.008530 1.25e-02 1.59e-02 1.63e-02 1.82e-04
# 4: 18100 0.019700 3.06e-02 3.29e-02 2.43e-04 1.90e-04
# 5: 24100 0.000038 3.36e-05 3.93e-07 8.20e-07 5.38e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a 24100x24100 matrix out of a sparse triplet representation (each row represents a nonzero cell in your matrix)? This can be done using the Matrix library:

```
sp <- read.table(text="100     100     0.216
6100    100     0.00109
12100   100     0.00853
18100   100     0.0197
24100   100     0.000038
100     6100    0.506
6100    6100    0.00231
12100   6100    0.0125
18100   6100    0.0306
24100   6100    3.36E-005
100     12100   0.506
6100    12100   0.00231
12100   12100   0.0159
18100   12100   0.0329
24100   12100   3.93E-007
100     18100   0.506
6100    18100   0.00292
12100   18100   0.0163
18100   18100   0.000243
24100   18100   8.20E-007
100     24100   0.506
6100    24100   0.00322
12100   24100   0.000182
18100   24100   0.00019
24100   24100   5.38E-006")

library(Matrix)
spMat <- spMatrix(24100, 24100, sp[,1], sp[,2], sp[,3])
```

This is a sparse matrix, meaning that it only allocates memory for the nonzero cells:

```
object.size(spMat)
# 1872 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using dataframes, you can convert to a triplet form of matrices using the `simple_triplet_matrix` in the `slam` package or the `dgTMatrix` class in `SparseM` using the `sparseMatrix` function.

From there, you can convert to a matrix using `as.matrix`

ex:

```
library(slam)
mat = simple_triplet_matrix(c(1,3,4),c(2,4,5),c(2,4,2))
as.matrix(mat)
```